# What do Set-Theoretic (General) Topologists study?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I was reading in *Elementary Topology by O Viro, O Ivanov, V Kharlamov, and N Netsvetaev* and it caught my attention the following quotes by the authors:

"...As a research field (refering to General Topology), it was completed long time ago ...We warn the students..Do not hurry to fall in love with it too seriously, do not let imprinting happen. This field may seem to be charming, but it is not very active. It hardly provides as much room for exciting new research as most other fields"

my questions:
if General Topology was completed long time ago, then what do current General Topologist study ? what sort of questions do they try to answer ?

Comment: I think the best question to ask is more "Are there any general topologists anymore?" Because if there aren't the question is moot.

Comment: We still don't know if $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is normal in the box topology or not.

Comment: This should probably be closed as too broad. Suffice it to say, general/set-theoretic topology is still an active research area. A large percentage of the articles in [Topology and Its Applications](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/01668641) are in this area. Also, the book [Open Problems in Topology II](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444522085) lists a large number of outstanding open problems. Also, the recently published [Recent Progress in General Topology III](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9789462390232) is something to look at.

Comment: @Zelos: Of course there are. Gary Gruenhage has produced ten this century. Steve Watson is active. Angelo Bella. Mikhail Matveev. Raushan Buzyakova. And apart from Gary’s students and Steve, those are just a few that I’ve run into while answering questions here.

Comment: A similar question might be, "What do current linear algebraists study?"  Although it is an exaggeration to say that the subject is 'completed', it is not a major research area, and there is no broad programme of study as there is in subjects like Algebraic Topology, Algebraic Geometry or Number Theory.  So it's not really possible to answer the question in this format.

Comment: It is always easy to make comments of the "gloom and doom" type for the future of a subject area, but general topology has links with many fields. So you should at least look at the following, although this includes wide areas of topology http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/applications-of-topology-to-computer-science,